# Double URL for My Home Page in Open Cart

Tags: url, web, double, opencart

I am not a coder. I bought this Open Cart Template from Template Monster. Now, I noticed that my home page are:

1. [www.florenceblooms.com](http://www.florenceblooms.com)
2. [florenceblooms.com](http://florenceblooms.com)
3. http://www.florenceblooms.com/index.php?route=common/home.

How do I solve that, please?

Comment: you can put up a redirect in your htaccess file to direct to your 1st URL whenever anyone types the 2nd URL.

Comment: Thanks Rohit Batra. Can you please tell me how to do it step by step? If that is ok with you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to redirect your website url to

> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ RewriteRule (.*)
>
> http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

and in a 3rd URL, You need to do .htaccess for it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Vipul Jethva. Can you tell me how to do it step by step? If that is ok with you.

Comment: There is .htaccess file in your opencart root folder. You just copy and paste above code with your URL. so it will work as per your requirement.